# Compound IF Statement in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to link 2 Google Sheets with each other & need to create an `IF` statement. In Sheet 1 I have checkboxes: Yes, No, Maybe. 
In Sheet 2 I'd like a statement that says basically:

```
If A2=true,YES, 
IF A3=true,NO, 
IF A4=true,MAYBE
```

I keep getting errors. Is this possible?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score -1):

if your sheet is called **Sheet1** take this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2=TRUE; "YES";
 IF(Sheet1!A3=TRUE; "NO";
 IF(Sheet1!A4=TRUE; "MAYBE"; )))
```

if your sheet is called **Sheet 1** take this:

```
=IF('Sheet 1'!A2=TRUE; "YES";
 IF('Sheet 1'!A3=TRUE; "NO";
 IF('Sheet 1'!A4=TRUE; "MAYBE"; )))
```

Comment: This question was flagged as low-quality because its **length** and **content**. Please consider to add a brief description of your solutions and the an explanation about why you are including two alternatives.